# Is the Object.values(obj) method a "free" operation in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, optimization, javascript-objects

The JavaScript method `Object.values()` takes an object, and returns an array of all the object's values. For example:

```
const myObj = {
    prop1: 123,
    prop2: "Hello",
    prop3: "World!"
};
const myArr = Object.values(myObj);
console.log(myArr); // logs the following array: [123, "Hello", "World!"]
```

My question is, does JavaScript internally loop through *all* the values of the object to create the array every time I call `Object.values()`?

Or does JavaScript perhaps just return a "wrapper" array over the object's internal values (if one exists)?

Hypothetically, if you were using such an object as a "dictionary" with 10,000 keys/values, it would be quite expensive for JavaScript to loop every time you called `Object.values()`.

Comment: Yes it does create a new array every time — [here's the spec](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/fundamental-objects.html#sec-object.values). If that addresses your question, I can write it up as an answer. If not, what did I miss?

Comment: @jsejcksn make it an answer and ill choose it

Comment: Trival to prove it's not "free": creating an array needs the elements. If you were to return some existing array of values, then what would `Object.values(obj).pop()` do?

Comment: @VLAZ to play devil's advocate, maybe the implementation only creates a new array when you do something that modifies it (like `pop()` in your example). I could see an optimization like that being practical.

Comment: @user3163495 Well as an optimisation that is always possible. IIRC, there are engines that can optimise `for (const key of Object.keys(obj))` to avoid allocating an array and filling it beforehand. But JavaScript does not specify that such an optimisation should or must happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is, does JavaScript internally loop through all the values of the object to create the array every time I call `Object.values()`?

According to the ECMAScript spec [20.1.2.23](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/fundamental-objects.html#sec-object.values): **Yes** — every time the method is invoked, a new array is created containing all of the object's enumerable own properties.

> ### 20.1.2.23 Object.values ( `O` )
>
> This function performs the following steps when called:
>
> 1. Let `obj` be ? [ToObject](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/abstract-operations.html#sec-toobject)(`O`).
> 2. Let `valueList` be ? [EnumerableOwnProperties](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/abstract-operations.html#sec-enumerableownproperties)(`obj`, value).
> 3. Return [CreateArrayFromList](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/abstract-operations.html#sec-createarrayfromlist)(`valueList`).

---

Note that you can create a (lazy) `IterableIterator` of an object's [entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) (and avoid creating a new array) using a generator function like the one shown below. If you only need to iterate part of a very large collection, it can be an optimization:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&jsx=4&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAogdsATgSwgZwDwBUoQB7ARwAmaUA9gEYBWEAxsAHxQC8UA3gFBRQDaA0lGRwoAawghyAMyhYAugC4+-ADSyBcuQG5OAX17jJM+Ts5SArnAbJycAFRDCiAIaF4SVJhz5CJMlVoGRgAKbgoaJSwVTgBKJQBxIggXYHJEDHcUdGxGNQA3cmRiZi4eKTSoYLpbNGAxCSERAJiOMJ5kGWCAeRp6YAA6AAtnNC6AdzhggLVDGJbSnkWQVAAbYj5DNQCDCU0dRahdMKOjzk4AenOoAFU0CAUz6rhaqABbEB7qVlaeMERyMAARiUgIATABmaK-f5gUFKABEAAkICsVuR4VCoH8AeCEQB1NJrACEGLC2LAABYlFJnCs7tFdKZyohKk8XjsQPlaeYIHIKDJkE5XBBMp5gu9PnMfkJOoZWCw2PDyaD4S08tyIPsDtqddrLgA9AD8YQ6lVAkGkUHVKx58sVlHI5BWEGccFV9RAWt13p9OoNxqOQA)

```ts
type Entries<T extends object> = {
  [K in keyof T]: [K, T[K]];
}[keyof T];

function* iterateEntries<T extends object>(
  obj: T,
): Generator<Entries<T>, void> {
  for (const key in obj) {
    if (Object.hasOwn(obj, key)) {
      yield [key, obj[key]];
    }
  }
}


// Use:

const myObj = {
  prop1: 123,
  prop2: "Hello",
  prop3: "World!",
  prop4: false,
};

for (const [key, value] of iterateEntries(myObj)) {
  if (key === "prop2") value;
                     //^? const value: string
  if (typeof value === "boolean") key;
                                //^? const key: "prop4"
}
```

References:

- [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)
- [`Object.hasOwn()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwn)

Answer (score 2):

I suspect this question comes from a .NET / C# background which features many iterables implementing the `IEnumerable<T>` interface which allows for lazy evaluation during iteration and `IQueryable<T>` which can implement take advantage of expression analysis to optimize access further.

JavaScript *can* implement both of these with [generators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator) (for `IEnumerable`) and [AST analysis](https://esprima.org/) (for `IQueryable`, nobody really does this).

With that said, the JavaScript "Standard Library" (if you will) does not do either of them much.

There might be others, but the only two notable constructs to return Iterators (generators) are in [`Set` and `Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/values) when calling their enumeration methods (`keys()`, `values()`).

[image]

Very long-winded way of saying: No, it's not free. Don't expect enumeration to be free in general when it comes to JS.